# C++ Win32 Getting a registry key

Tags: c++, winapi

```
const char* Launcher::GetProjectName()
{
    PVOID data;
    LPDWORD pcbData;
    HKEY OpenResult;
    LSTATUS status = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Environment", NULL, KEY_READ, &OpenResult);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Could not found registry key 'Environment'";
    }
    else
    {
        LPCWSTR project_name_key = L"project_name";
        DWORD data_type;
        WCHAR value[255];
        PVOID pvData = value;
        DWORD size = sizeof(value);
        status = RegGetValue(OpenResult, NULL, project_name_key, RRF_RT_ANY, &data_type, pvData, &size);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            LOG(ERROR) << "Could not found registry value 'project_name'";
        }
        else
        {
            switch (data_type)
            {
            case REG_DWORD:
                wprintf(L"Value data: %x\n", *(DWORD*)pvData);
                break;
            case REG_SZ:
                wprintf(L"Value data: %s\n", (PWSTR)pvData);
            }

        }
        RegCloseKey(OpenResult);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get this registry key I made named "project_name" and return it as a `char*` or a `std::string`. However, I'm getting garbage data in pvData. What am I doing wrong here? I've seen some other stackoverflow posts and tried to replicate their setup as well but nothing is working. My entire goal here is to retrieve an environment variable using the windows registry.

Comment: I compiled your code, changed `"project_name"` to  be `"Path"` and commented out the log statements. It works fine. Although I suspect returning a `char*` instead of a `std::string` could lead to issues if you are returning a local variable.

Comment: Yeah it works, but I don't know how I'm supposed to convert a void* to a string. PVOID is a typedef of void*. How can I convert this to a human readable string?

Comment: In your code, `pvData` and `value` are the same thing.  Your wide string result is captured in `value`.  Are you really asking how to convert a wide string to an ANSI string?

Comment: `return std::string((const char*)pvData);` This seemed to do the trick, but I feel like this is undefined behavior and could potentially be a bug?

Comment: Oh I see the issue.... answer incoming.

Comment: Also, `value` seems to be a bunch of chinese characters when I look in the debugger.

Comment: `value` appears to be asian characters because the debugger is interpreting your ANSI sequence of bytes as unicode when `value` is declared as `WCHAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a mismatch of ANSI and Unicode expectations. Your code is likely compiling for ANSI, but you're passing a wide-char buffer.  Let's just explicitly call the `A` version of the Registry functions so you can stay in the ANSI string space.

Instead of this:

```
WCHAR value[255];
PVOID pvData = value;
DWORD size = sizeof(value);
status = RegGetValue(OpenResult, NULL, project_name_key, RRF_RT_ANY, &data_type, pvData, &size);
```

Use this:

```
char value[255];
DWORD size = sizeof(value);
status = RegGetValueA(OpenResult, NULL, project_name_key, RRF_RT_ANY, &data_type, value, &size);
```

Then, return a `std::string` as follows:

Declare your function to return a string, not a pointer:

```
const std::string Launcher::GetProjectName()
```

Then simply return `value` as a string;

```
return std::string(value);
```

Comment: Seems to work! I noticed you work at microsoft. Do you know any good resources for better understanding the win32 api? It's very verbose and hard to learn everything with all the different typedefs that exist. Like PVOID is just a typedef of void*. The documentation is great but it's pretty steep learning curve. Any tips for understanding it better so I can write quality code?

Comment: Classic Win32 programming books include [the Petzold book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_08KCG9S519AAHD75E87K) and [the Richter book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572315482/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_FW0JE2XPYVHXPETN90G3). But these books **used** to save money.

Comment: What do you mean they used to save money?

Comment: Typo
 I was suggesting to **buy** the books used. "buy" in place of "but"